# ¿Cómo puedo usar bucles for para convertir las columnas y su contenido de una df a unos más organizados en Python? librería Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, bucles, dataframe

Obtuve la siguiente `df` como el resultado de un proceso previo que hizo unos [Productos Cartesianos](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producto_cartesiano):

```
  Permutations                        FilePermutations
0 Fondo+Cuerpo+Ojos+Color+Pinzas+Puas Oceano.png+Cuerpo_cangrejo.png+Antenas.png+Amarillo.png+None+None
1 Fondo+Cuerpo+Ojos+Color+Pinzas+Puas Oceano.png+Cuerpo_cangrejo.png+Antenas.png+Amarillo.png+None+Arena.png
2 Fondo+Cuerpo+Ojos+Color+Pinzas+Puas Oceano.png+Cuerpo_cangrejo.png+Antenas.png+Amarillo.png+None+Marron.png
3 Fondo+Cuerpo+Ojos+Color+Pinzas+Puas Oceano.png+Cuerpo_cangrejo.png+Antenas.png+Amarillo.png+None+Purpura.png
4 Fondo+Cuerpo+Ojos+Color+Pinzas+Puas Oceano.png+Cuerpo_cangrejo.png+Antenas.png+Amarillo.png+None+Verde.png
.
.
.
```

Quisiera convertir esa `df` a esta, donde cada `"_"` se convirtió en `" "` y cada `".png"` al final de una palabra se borró:

```
0 | Fondo | Oceano | Cuerpo | Cuerpo cangrejo | Ojos | Antenas | Color | Amarillo | Pinzas | None | Puas | None
1 | Fondo | Oceano | Cuerpo | Cuerpo cangrejo | Ojos | Antenas | Color | Amarillo | Pinzas | None | Puas | Arena
2 | Fondo | Oceano | Cuerpo | Cuerpo cangrejo | Ojos | Antenas | Color | Amarillo | Pinzas | None | Puas | Marron
3 | Fondo | Oceano | Cuerpo | Cuerpo cangrejo | Ojos | Antenas | Color | Amarillo | Pinzas | None | Puas | Purpura
4 | Fondo | Oceano | Cuerpo | Cuerpo cangrejo | Ojos | Antenas | Color | Amarillo | Pinzas | None | Puas | Verde
.
.
.
```

**He intentado el siguiente código:**

```
import pandas as pd

old_df = pd.read_csv("cartesian.csv", index_col=0)
new_columns = old_df.iloc[0]['Permutations'].split("+")
new_data = []
for i in range(0, len(old_df)):
    row_data = old_df.iloc[i]['FilePermutations'].split("+")
    current_data = []
    for j, column in enumerate(new_columns):
        current_data.append(f"{column} {row_data[j]}")
    new_data.append(current_data)

updated_df = pd.DataFrame(data=new_data, columns=new_columns)
print(updated_df)
```

**Pero sólo he logrado obtener esta** `nueva_df`:

```
              Fondo                      Cuerpo  ...       Pinzas              Puas
0  Fondo Oceano.png  Cuerpo Cuerpo_cangrejo.png  ...  Pinzas None         Puas None
1  Fondo Oceano.png  Cuerpo Cuerpo_cangrejo.png  ...  Pinzas None    Puas Arena.png
2  Fondo Oceano.png  Cuerpo Cuerpo_cangrejo.png  ...  Pinzas None   Puas Marron.png
3  Fondo Oceano.png  Cuerpo Cuerpo_cangrejo.png  ...  Pinzas None  Puas Purpura.png
4  Fondo Oceano.png  Cuerpo Cuerpo_cangrejo.png  ...  Pinzas None    Puas Verde.png
..                                          ...  ...                            ...

[360 rows x 6 columns]
```

Puedo obtener algo de asistencia por favor?

Answer (score 1):

a bote pronto, se me ocurre que antes del split, hagas un replace de la extensión .png a blanco o vacio.

`row_data = old_df.iloc[i]['FilePermutations'].replace('.png', '').split("+")`

espero haberte orientado.